# Why does method called from another controller dont change the scene?

Tags: java, button, javafx, controller, scenebuilder

I got scene first.fxml with firstController, it is BorderPane with one button(birthCert) in the left side.

When i click on button(birthCert) i succefully load second.fxml into center of BorderPane.

```java
    @FXML
    void birthCert(ActionEvent event) {

        Parent root;
        try {
            root = load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
            id_borderPane.setCenter(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

second.fxml is conected with secondController class and have 1 button(sendRequest). When this button is clicked i create instance of firstController and i want call method setscene to load third.fxml into center of borderPane.

third.fxml only show message "Your request was sent".

Problem is, when i call method setscene in class secondController with instance of firstController

```java
c.setscene();
```

```java
 public void setscene() {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = load(getClass().getResource("third.fxml"));
            id_borderPane.setCenter(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

it don't load third.fxml into center of BorderPane, nothing happens just second.fxml remains loaded.

I tried control printing and i tested if root is null but printing works fine and root is not null so i really don't understand what can cause that it doesn't show third.fxml in center of BorderPane

Here is the whole code:

```java
package controllers;

import static javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class firstController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane id_borderPane;

    @FXML
    void birthCert(ActionEvent event) {

        Parent root;
        try {
            root = load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
            id_borderPane.setCenter(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setscene() {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = load(getClass().getResource("third.fxml"));
            id_borderPane.setCenter(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

```java
package controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class secondController{

    @FXML
    void SendRequset(MouseEvent event) throws IOException  {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("first.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        UserGUISendReqController c = loader.getController(); // instance of firstController
        c.setscene();
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot for help :)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: When you do a test printout in `setscene()` check if `root` is not null.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
FirstController
|- SecondController
```

Then in second controller you click the button to add third controller you're doing

```
FirstController
|- SecondController
   |- new FirstController.setScene()
```

You should instantiate a new FirstController, you should either call up to SecondController parent, or pass the references to FirstController into second controller somehow.

You want to use either getParent on SecondController or some other method of passing the active FirstController into the SecondController so that when you call to it, it's the right one.

ps. People will also comment on your naming convention not following standards.